# Button's onclick function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I don't know why this function is not working.

HTML:

```
<button id="welcomehomebtnlogin" type="button" onclick="loginformfunction()">Login</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function loginformfunction()
{
    document.getElementById("welcomehomebtndiv").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("loginform").style.display = "block";
}
```

What I want to do is: if the user clicks on the "Login" button, one form will disappear with `display = "none"`. The button is part of this form, and it will also disappear. Then a second form will be shown.

It's not working; any ideas why?

Comment: Any errors? Im looking at the code right now. Try putting a console.log into the function to see if its actually called.

Comment: Works as described here: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/VeYbMe. The error must be elsewhere. I'd also like to know if you see any errors in your [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: Whats the welcomehomebtndiv?

Comment: ok.so i'm doing this on Cordova App and now its working fine on app but ,interestingly it is not working on browser.

Comment: index.html:46 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-7v88ef4iy1Ow+iK9VyBkeqfMy4L+lpUCs3usT8Rpk+M='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: index.html:42 Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: above are the errors i can see in console.

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle. Your code doesn't have error. May be you are doing mistake else.. Or even may be javascript is somehow disabled in your browser

Comment: document.getElementById("welcomehomebtnlogin").addEventListener("mouseover", loginformfunction); thia mouseover event working well but onclick is not working .

Answer (score 2):

Your code look fine, check the basic example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
function loginformfunction()
{
    document.getElementById("welcomehomebtndiv").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("loginform").style.display = "block";
}

document.getElementById("welcomehomebtnlogin").addEventListener('click', loginformfunction, false);
```

```css
#loginform{
    display: none; 
}
```

```html
<div id='welcomehomebtndiv'>
  Welcome HOME div
  <button id="welcomehomebtnlogin" type="button">Login</button>
</div>

<div id='loginform'>
  Login div
</div>
```

Comment: i know code is fine ..but its not working ! keeping in mind that the button is the part of same div which i am going to remove or display="none". i tell you one more interesting thing mousover() works fine but onclick() dosent .

Comment: Okay @RAOHAMMAS try my updated answer replacing `inline-event` by ading listner in js code.

Comment: but the problem is Its working fine with mouseover()  .

Comment: The problems above in comment should be disapear when you use not a inline-event like i suggested in my answer, recheck please your console.